# Smallest string containing sets of letters

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, polynomial-time, substrings

I am looking for a solution to this problem:
Given multiple sets of letters (Set0={a,b,c,d}, Set1={d,e,f,g}, Set2={a,b,e,g}, ...), what is the minimal length of the string containing all the sets. The sets have to be present as one substring, it is possible to duplicate letters in the final string, and it is also possible to permutate letters in one set.

E.g.:

**abc|def|gabe** (strlen = 10, sets are like: Set0, Set1, Set2)

Where the Set0 is starting at the index 0, Set1 is starting at the index 3, Set2 is starting at the index 7.

Another better solution is:

**ab|egf|dabc** (strlen = 9, sets are like: Set2, Set1, Set0)

Where the Set0 is starting at the index 5, Set1 is starting at the index 2, Set2 is starting at the index 0.

Comment: This problem looks like a variant of the shortest common superstring problem. To be clear, is any permutation of the strings allowed?

Comment: And @Discretelizard you can permute the Sets, the final string can be Set0, Set2, Set1 for instance

Comment: Is this re-phrasal of your problem correct? Given $n$ sets of characters, find a string $s$ such that for each set there is a substring of $s$ containing those, and only those characters. This is assuming sets can overlap, so if the sets are $\{a, c\}$ and $\{a, b\}$ then $cab$ would be a string that solves it.

Comment: @orlp Yes, plus you can have duplicated letters, so one of the best solution for {a,b,c}, {b,c,d} and {c,d,a} would be "abcda"

Comment: @J.Doe If set0={a} and set1={a}, do we need that the letter a appears twice in the superstring? Or is it guaranteed that the initial sets are different?

Comment: The initial sets are known to be not identical (there are no sets n and m such as Sn = Sm). There are no other constraints on the sets, the intersection of two randomly chosen sets can be empty, non empty, one included in the other, but they are not identical.

Comment: @J.Doe In [orlp's formulation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/108577/#comment231860_108577),  $s$ is allowed to contain duplicate letters. Or, $s$ is not forbidden to have duplicate letters. We would have shortest superstring $axbxc$ for sets $\{a,x\}$, $\{a,b,x\}$, $\{a,b,c,x\}$, $\{b,c,x\}$, $\{c,x\}$ where substring $axbxc$ corresponds to the set $\{a,b,c,x\}$. Is this your intention?

Comment: @Apass.Jack The final string **s** can contain duplicated letters, but each set can be found in the string **s** without duplicated letter. The example that you gave would not work since there are 2 **x** in **axbxc**

Comment: @J.Doe Could you please explain the motivation of the problem in the post? In case you read it somewhere, please add an accessible reference.